# Añadir opciones a un SELECT, me crea opciones en blanco

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando añadir opciones a un `select`, pero lo que ocurre es que **se añaden pero vacías**: `<option></option>`. Les muestro mi código:

```
//AQUÍ MIRO EL VALOR DE UN SELECT ANTERIOR, PORQUE DE ESTE DEPENDE EL RESTO
var typeID = document.getElementById("type");
var type = typeID.options[typeID.selectedIndex].value;

//AQUÍ PONGO LOS VALORES DEL SELECT PARA AMBOS CASOS
item0={
    o1:{value:1,text:"Texto 1"},
    o1:{value:1,text:"Texto 2"},
    o2:{value:2,text:"Texto 3"}
}
item1={
    o1:{value:1,text:"Texto 1"},
    o2:{value:2,text:"Texto 2"}
    }

//SI EL VALOR DE "TYPE" ES 0, SE AÑADEN UNOS SELECT, SI ES 0, OTROS.
if (type == 0) {
    $.each(item0, function (i, item) {
        $('#action').append($('<option>', { 
            value: item0.value,
            text : item0.text 
        }));
    });
} else if (type == 1) {
    $.each(item1, function (i, item) {
        $('#action').append($('<option>', { 
            value: item1.value,
            text : item1.text 
        }));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con tu código seria así:

```js
const item0={
  o1:{value:1,text:"Texto 1"},
  o1:{value:1,text:"Texto 2"},
  o2:{value:2,text:"Texto 3"}
};

const item1={
  o1:{value:1,text:"Texto 1"},
  o2:{value:2,text:"Texto 2"}
};

$("#type").change(function(){
  
  $('#action option').remove();
  const type = parseInt($(this).val());
  
  if (type == 0) {
    $.each(item0, function (i, item) {
      $('#action').append($('<option>', { 
        value : item.value,
        text  : item.text 
      }));
    });
  } else if (type == 1) {
    $.each(item1, function (i, item) {
      $('#action').append($('<option>', { 
         value: item.value,
         text : item.text 
      }));
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<select id="type">
  <option selected disabled>Selecciona un tipo</option>
  <option value="0">Tipo 0</option>
  <option value="1">Tipo 1</option>
</select>

<select id="action"><select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

El problema era como accedias a los valores, antes lo hacias así:

```
$('#action').append($('<option>', { 
  value: item0.value,
  text : item0.text 
}));
```

y es:

```
$('#action').append($('<option>', { 
  value: item.value,
  text : item.text 
}));
```

Cuando haces el **$.each** ya estas indicando que array estas usando y para acceder a los valores no tienes que indicar nuevamente de que array viene el **value** y el **text**

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en cómo accedes a los datos que declaras para cada item. Pongo un ejemplo con el item0, el cual declaro como un array con los objetos y accedo a cada uno utilizando el índice i que declaras en la función al recorrer el array para rellenar las opciones.

```js
item0=[
    {value:1,text:"Texto 1"},
    {value:2,text:"Texto 2"},
    {value:3,text:"Texto 3"}
];

    $.each(item0, function (i, item) {
        $('#action').append($('<option>', { 
            value: item0[i].value,
            text : item0[i].text 
        }));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="action">
<option value="0">selecciona</option>
</select>
```